# hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar FileNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am newbie and I am trying to run a hive query

```
 hive> SELECT xpath('<a><b id="foo">b1</b><b
 id="bar">b2</b></a>','//@id') FROM src LIMIT 1;
```

when I execute the above command I get the following error

> Job Submission failed with exception
>   'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist:
>   hdfs://localhost:9100/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar)'
>   Execution failed with exit status: 2 Obtaining error information
>
> Task failed! Task ID:   Stage-1

It is trying to look for hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar in hdfs. But this file is available under $HIVE_HOME/lib. why should it be uploaded to HDFS?

I have the following setting at the start of the hive

~/.hiverc
set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true;

If I add this hadoop property in hive-site.xml then it gives me the required output

```
 <property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>file:///</value>    
 </property>
```

but ideally I want to set it to

```
   <value>hdfs://localhost</value>
```

as I have other hadoop specific java programs that use hdfs. What is the mistake I am making here. Is there a configuration that I need to set while starting up.

As requested $PATH information

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hive/bin
```

Please help.

Many thanks

Comment: Have not done this in a  while, but I am pretty sure you should have your $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive set to execute Hive CLI query. You should post the output of your $PATH in your question above

Comment: Thanks. I have added the $PATH information. 

Also, I am able to execute hive and I am able to get inside the shell.

When I run the select command inside the shell I am getting the errors.

Comment: Try the following in Terminal xyz$ export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive and then rerun your Hive Query

Comment: Thanks but as you can see $HIVE_HOME/bin has been already set here in $PATH